# Custom listener to show ExoPlayer UI Controls

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Currently playback controllers shows up by onClick event which includes onLongPress, onDrag etc. But I want to show UI controls only when onTouch event is fired.

Is there any method to achieve this level of customization?